# Problema QR Template Blade Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, blade, qr

Estoy trabajando convirtiendo desde backend con php un código de barra en QR con:

```
use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;
```

para luego enviármelo como parámetro a mi `template blade laravel` y mostrarlo en una boleta, al generarlo se genera correctamente, se almacena localmente (si lo busco y lo abro puedo verlo y escanearlo correctamente), inclusive en mi `log` se manda correctamente la ruta pero el `template` no me lo renderiza, para mostrarlo uso una etiqueta `<img/>` y lo paso en el `src="{{$qr}}"`. ¿Alguna idea de porque podría ser el problema?.